# After ontouch, it can't go ondrag on Android

Tags: android

(I deleted all code, because the below code is not working either.)

#### Additional information and short summary - the real problem

This is interesting. I have another project a simple activity. There, I can drag. Now in this project, I block commented everywhere. There are only a few lines, like another project, but still no drag.

```
 Drag is in progress, but there is no drag window handle.
```

Sometimes it says. I also searched it, but I could not do it.

The code is now:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "matching ggame OnCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_matchgame);
    setupForGame();
    Log.d(TAG, "matching game OnCreate ends");
}//oncreate end

void setupForGame(){
    Log.d(TAG, "matching game setupforgame");

    imageAnswer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAnswer);

    imageAnswer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAnswer);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ontouch never");
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View receivingLayoutView, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ondrag start");
```

And still not going inside.

I made it static to see if that is the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    tools:context=".games.MatchingGame">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAnswer"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:src="@drawable/b3_1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is same as another project, but it is not working. I looked at all possibilities and debugged.

And please don't ask for drag method code; it is not important. It can't enter it.

When I hold and drag image, this comes to the log in a loop until I leave:

```
I/SPRDHWComposer: util[1759] warning: osdLayer width 111, stride 112, not equal!
```

And when I leave the image:

```
V/WindowManager: rotationForOrientationLw(orient=0, last=1); user=0 USER_ROTATION_LOCKED sensorRot
V/WindowOrientationListener: getProposedRotation : mEnabled = false, mUsedautorotioansensor =true
 W/WindowManager: Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle.
```

I also made this if the touch is problem, but it is still the same:

```
imageAnswer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { Log.d(TAG, "ontouch down");

        //Log.d(TAG,"parent "+ String.valueOf(img1.getParent()));
        Log.d(TAG, "view "+String.valueOf(v));

        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
```

This is my old project that works with drag and drop. I can't see the difference:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/540a70e05de6d765e20896b47deb7eb2

When I do this

```
imageAnswer.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {  Log.d(TAG, "drag");

        return false;
    }
});
```

It does not work either. No log.

Also this does not give a log:

```
imageAnswer.setOnDragListener(new dropListener());

private class dropListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {Log.d("Chic","ondrag");
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
 }
```

There is difference between the two projects:

[image: Differences between projects]

**Can this be the reason?**

I tried also to put all setondrag setontouch inside oncreate.

Comment: Maybe u shud go thru developer docs once to see what ur missing..
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I seen (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664585/how-to-make-ondraglistener-and-ontouchlistener-work-together)), onTouch and onDrag simply don't work together. Why not put all of you code in in onDrag? Judging by your code, it should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

Use [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) instead of `ImageView`.

With the reference of that site:

> TouchImageView extends ImageView and supports all of ImageView’s functionality.
>   In addition, TouchImageView adds pinch zoom, dragging, fling, double tap zoom functionality and other animation polish. The intention is for TouchImageView to mirror as closely as possible the functionality of zoomable images in Gallery apps.

The problem will be solved it will support both **Drag** as well as **Touch**.